Help with a lemma on the argument of a qubit after transformation

From:
King, R. (2023). An improved approximation algorithm for quantum max-cut on triangle-free graphs. Quantum, 7, 1180.
I have trouble understanding item 3 of the above lemma. Here $n_k \cdot \sigma_k$ denotes the linear combination of non identity Pauli matrices. Can anyone tell me why that is true?
Edit:
Let $U_1$ and $U_2$ be uniformly distributed on $[0,2\pi]$. Both these variables have the same pdf $f(x) = 1/(2 \pi)$. Consider $S = (U_1 - U_2 \mod 2 \pi)$. We compute the distribution of $S$.
$$ \begin{aligned} f_S(s) &= \int_0^s f(t) f(t-s+2 \pi) dt + \int_s^{2\pi} f(t) f(t-s) dt \\
&= \int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{1}{4 \pi^2} dt = \frac{1}{2 \pi}.  \end{aligned}$$
Hence, $S$ is also uniformly distributed on $[0,2\pi]$.

I'm unfamiliar with this line of work and have not read the paper, so I may misinterpret the notations. Especially, I don't understand why $\sigma = (X, Y, Z)$ is indexed with $k$.
At first glance, it looks like the full argument could go like this.
If $n_k \in S^2$ and it is sampled from the "equator," then we can write:
$$n_k = (\cos\theta_k, \sin \theta_k, 0)^T,$$
where $\theta_k$ is a uniform random variable.
Then,
$$P_k = n_k \cdot \sigma = \cos \theta_k X + \sin \theta_k Y,$$
where $\sigma := (X, Y, Z)$. I guess not indexing $\sigma$ would imply a single-qubit case.
Let $|v_i\rangle = |0\rangle$ and $|v_j\rangle=|1\rangle$. I make this choice of $|v_i\rangle$ and $|v_j\rangle$ because for the vectors $v_i, v_j \in S^2$, we have $v_i \cdot n_k = 0$ and $v_j \cdot n_k = 0$. Therefore, we get:
\begin{align}
\langle v_i| P_j |v_j\rangle &= \langle v_i|\left( \cos \theta_j X + \sin \theta_j Y \right)|v_j\rangle\\
&= \langle 0|\left( \cos \theta_j X + \sin \theta_j Y \right)|1\rangle\\
&= \cos \theta_j -i \sin \theta_j\\
&= e^{-i \theta_j}.
\end{align}
In the above, I took advantage of the item 2. of the lemma, which states that $P_k|v_k\rangle$ is the negative of $|v_k\rangle$ on the Bloch sphere. In other words, $P_k|0\rangle \equiv |1\rangle$ up to a phase factor.
Now, if you do the same computation for $\langle v_j| P_i |v_i\rangle$, you will get $e^{i \theta_i}$. Hence, we have:
$$\arg \langle v_i| P_j |v_j\rangle \langle v_j| P_i |v_i\rangle = \arg e^{i(\theta_i - \theta_j)}.$$
Putting it all together yields:
$$\gamma_{ij} = \pi - \theta_i + \theta_j,$$
and as stated in the hint $\theta_i$ and $\theta_j$ are independent and uniformly random.
I'm not entirely sure if I correctly understood the lemma cause I don't have knowledge of the context. So, my guess of what's going on might be off. However, if this is the derivation, then I'm a bit dubious if $\gamma_{ij}$ is uniformly random. First, we have $\arg$ function that may modify the range and distribution of $\theta_i -\theta_j$. Second, even if $\theta_i$ and $\theta_j$ are independent and uniformly random, then their difference is not necessarily uniformly random.

That's nice, thank you! I'm wondering of your choice of $v_i$ and $v_j$ though. In your example, both $v_i$ and $v_j$ are orthogonal to the same $n_k$, which is not necessarily the case I think. As for the difference of 2 uniform random variables, in general, this is not uniformly distributed. But the subtraction is meant to be modulo 2 pi, due to the arg function, and then it works out.

Hi, $v_i$ and $v_j$ are orthogonal to all possible vectors on the equator because $v_i$ and $v_j$ are at the poles. About difference of random variables, even if it is modulo 2pi it is not given that the difference is uniformly random. Try working out their convolution and see the distribution you get. So far, their lemma argument about uniform randomness is far from being convincing, at least to me.

Yes, I understand that $v_i$ and $v_j$ are the poles. But why are you allowed to assume that they are both poles? This is not stated in the lemma. Sure, you can assume some rotation, but this only allows you to assume that only one of $v_i$ and $v_j$ are poles, not both. As for the uniform distribution, I've done the convolution that shows the difference modulo $2 \pi$ is also uniformly distributed. Check my edit for the details.
